# How to make VariableSized GridView Item?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to do a VariableSizedWrapGrid for the item within the wrapgrid. 
[image]

Something like this. 
The group title above store all the child item show on photo. 
After scroll to right hand, another group title with the child shown as below. 
 Anyone have any idea how to do so?

I was able to display group title with child item as below. The only things i unable to achieve is the variable size of the child item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can go is to use the GridView's built-in selector properties.

See my blog [entry](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/sloscialo/archive/2013/03/08/windows-8-gridview-and-variable-sized-items.aspx).

In a nutshell, you can create a custom StyleSelector.  All you have to do is override thee StyleSelectorCore() method and put in your logic to choose a style that defines the column or row spans.

You'll need to get the default GridViewItem style template through Blend or an online resource and create a default explicit style.  Then create new styles BasedOn the explicit one like so:

```
<Style x:Key="DoubleHeightGridViewItemStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultGridViewItemStyle}"
       TargetType="GridViewItem">
       <Setter Property="VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpan"
               Value="2" />
</Style>
```

For this to work, you'll also need to change the GridView's ItemsPanel template to use a VariableSizedWrapGrid.

Finally, by creating a custom DataTemplateSelector, you'll be able to change the DataTemlates of your bound items.  You'll need to do this unless your over-sized items can use the same DataTemplate as the default sized one.

Answer (score 2):

Updating this because some other helpful things have emerged since the question was asked.  My colleague Jerry Nixon has a nice post describing how to create variable-sized items in a GridView:

- [Windows 8 Beauty Tip: Using a VariableSizedWrapGrid in a GridView makes Grids Prettier](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html)

Short version, you can make a custom `GridView` that implements `PrepareContainerForItemOverride`.

There's also more details in an earlier example (from May) that Mark Rideout posted:

- [How To: Create a Variable Sized Grouped GridView (like the store)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/966aa897-1413-46f0-bef7-663de36f9423)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for doing it in C#: http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/customizing-gridview-items-in-metro-app-4/

Comment: It is not grouped as well. 
I have look through all the resources online.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about C# and XMAL code of doing this. But in Javascript, instead of creating the template in HTML, you can create the item template in javascript by doing something like this

```
function MyItemTemplate(itemPromise) {
    return itemPromise.then(function (currentItem) {
        var result = document.createElement("div");

        //use source data to decide what size to make the
        //ListView item and apply different css class to it
        result.className = currentItem.data.type;
        result.style.overflow = "hidden";

        // Display image
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.className = "regularListIconTextItem-Image";
        image.src = currentItem.data.picture;
        result.appendChild(image);

        var body = document.createElement("div");
        body.className = "regularListIconTextItem-Detail";
        body.style.overflow = "hidden";

        // Display title
        var title = document.createElement("h4");
        title.innerText = currentItem.data.title;
        body.appendChild(title);

        // Display text
        var fulltext = document.createElement("h6");
        fulltext.innerText = currentItem.data.text;
        body.appendChild(fulltext);

        result.appendChild(body);
        return result;
    });
}
```

Source of this code is in the ListView Item Templates sample of the [consumer preview sample package](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples). Unfortunately, I was not able to find the C# version of it.

Hope this helps to some degree.

Comment: Thx for reply. Yupz. i am searching for official version of this. While i only able to search Javascript. Due to time matter, i unable to implement Javascript as i hv no interaction with Javascript b4. I need C# n XAML style of variable grid view ><